# Ansible Integration without Tower?

Tags: ansible, manageiq

I don't have a tower license but have an extensive list of playbooks I want to expose via manageiq. Is there any way to add ansible playbooks and run them as shown in the [Announcement](http://cloudformsblog.redhat.com/2017/05/31/red-hat-cloudforms-4-5-ga/#more-1915)

Comment: That announcement says nothing about requiring Tower.

Answer (score 0):

The CloudForms system now has the ability to execute Ansible playbooks when an API is called or a button within its GUI is pressed, it does not need Ansible Tower to perform these actions.

See the links in this announcement for additional details and examples showing how to call playbooks from CloudForms.

http://cloudformsblog.redhat.com/2017/05/31/ansible-automation-inside-cloudforms/#more-1878